# Matching data two inputs

Tags: python

I have 2 inputs as follows:

```
input1 = ["order", "name", "age", "soul", "test", "chill", "thym", "transport", "lim"]
input2 = ["order", "age", "soul", "chill", "thym", "exe", "test", "lim"]
```

I want to match these 2 lists and want the output to have 2 columns as follows:

```
order order
name -
age age
soul soul
test -
chill chill
thym thym
transport - 
- exe
- test
lim lim
```

Output is obtained by matching two inputs

- If text is present in input 1, but not in input 2, then the first column output is the text of input 1 and the character -
- If text is present in input 2, but not in input 1, the first column outputs the character - and the text of input 2
- If text is present in both input 1 and 2 but their positions are different like in the case of the word `test` in 2 inputs, the output will be `test -` and `- test`.

In the case of text present in one input but not in another input, I can easily handle it with a normal search. But in case text is in both inputs like the word "test" in the example, I have not found a solution yet.

I want the output to be optimal by having the least number of `-` characters.

Comment: You forgot to post your *attempt* to solve this problem.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? If this is homework, please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask].

Comment: What if `input1 = ['A','B','C','Z']` and `input2 = ['A','C','B','Z']`?

Comment: `age` is in different position on both lists, why is it outputted as on same position? The same for `soul`

Comment: @ScottHunter With this input, output: A A; C -; B B; -C; Z Z or A A; B -; C C; - B; Z Z is ok. In the case of text present in one input but not in another input, I can easily handle it with a normal search. But in case text is in both inputs like the word "test" in the example, I don't know what to do. Do you have any suggestions to help me?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I want to optimize the output by having as few "-" characters as possible. In my output, the output seems to be the most optimal

Comment: If that "optimization" is a requirement, it should be included in the problem definition.

Comment: What is the logic associated with determining how to order items when different terms are at the same indices?  E.g. How do you determine, you can advance the index for input 1 and not for input 2 when you find 'name' at  index 1 for input 1 but not for input2?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```py
input1 = ["order", "name", "age", "soul", "test", "chill", "thym", "transport", "lim"]
input2 = ["order", "age", "soul", "chill", "thym", "exe", "test", "lim"]

i1, i2 = iter(input1), iter(input2)
v1, v2 = next(i1, None), next(i2, None)
n1, n2 = next(i1, None), next(i2, None)

while True:
    if v1 is None and v2 is None:
        break

    if v1 == v2:
        print(v1, v2)
        v1, v2 = n1, n2
        n1, n2 = next(i1, None), next(i2, None)
    elif v1 == n2:
        print("-", v2)
        print(v1, n2)
        v1, v2, n1, n2 = n1, next(i2, None), next(i1, None), next(i2, None)
    elif v2 == n1:
        print(v1, "-")
        print(n1, v2)
        v1, v2, n1, n2 = next(i1, None), n2, next(i1, None), next(i2, None)
    else:
        print(v1, "-")
        print("-", v2)
        v1, v2 = n1, n2
        n1, n2 = next(i1, None), next(i2, None)
```

Prints:

```
order order
name -
age age
soul soul
test -
chill chill
thym thym
transport -
- exe
- test
lim lim
```

---

With:

```py
input1 = ["A", "B", "C", "Z"]
input2 = ["A", "C", "B", "Z"]
```

Prints:

```
A A
- C
B B
C -
Z Z
```

Comment: I have a case input: input1 = ["order", "abc", "name", "age", "soul", "test", "chill", "thym"], 
input2 = ["order", "age", "soul", "chill", "thym", "exe", "test", "abc"], your code will not give the output I expected. No matter what, I really thank you!

Comment: @Kepler452B And what should be the output in this case?

Comment: The output I want is like this (it has the fewest "-" characters):
order order \n
abc - \n
name - \n
age age \n
soul soul \n
test - \n
chill chill \n
thym thym \n
- exe \n
- test \n
- abc \n.
In the input, I added the word "abc" to the 2nd position of input 1. In your code, you have moved the elements up by just 1 unit to match.

Comment: @Kepler452B In that case, I don't know how to solve this easily. Seems like mathematical optimization problem (you must test many combinations, and it will potentially *explode* if the lists are big.

Answer (score 0):

You gave different output, as per your question,
but I think you mean this:

```
input1 = ["order", "name", "age", "soul", "test", "chill", "thym", "transport", "lim"]
input2 = ["order", "age", "soul", "chill", "thym", "exe", "test", "lim"]
# Initialize empty result list
result = []

# Compare input1 to input2 and add missing items from input2
for item1 in input1:
    if item1 in input2:
        idx1 = input1.index(item1)
        idx2 = input2.index(item1)
        if idx1 == idx2:
            result.append((item1, item1))
        else:
            result.append((item1, '-'))
            result.append(('-', item1))
    else:
        result.append((item1, '-'))

# Compare input2 to input1 and add missing items from input1
for item2 in input2:
    if item2 not in input1:
        if item2 != "":
            result.append(('-', item2))

# Print the result in the desired format
for pair in result:
    print(pair[0], pair[1])
```

```
order order
name -
age -
- age
soul -
- soul
test -
- test
chill -
- chill
thym -
- thym
transport -
lim -
- lim
- exe
```